# Is it possible to order my request from 2 different fields? (elasticsearch)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch

I just started using Elasticsearch for 2 reasons

1. To speed up the time to get my results.
2. To get an ordering based on Full/Start/Sub/Fuzzy hits on specific fields.

For point 2 I'm having some troubles

I want to get the results from my request in this order.
[image with the order I want my results in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGrrD.png)

Is it possible without doing 8 different request or using the score?